# Setting variable names in jQuery from a variable

Tags: jquery

I'm using multiple select boxes on my website and use the `id` from each of these to select the `:selected` val and set it as a variable. You will see the 3 randomly chosen below and I'm stuck on adding the word val into the new way of setting multiple variables.

**before**

```
var maptypecontrolval       = $('#maptypecontrol>option:selected').val();
var pancontrolval       = $('#pancontrol>option:selected').val();
var clickzoomcontrolval     = $('#clickzoomcontrol>option:selected').val();
```

**after**

```
$(".settings select").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: What is your goal? You store the values of select boxes and then what?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do, but with a high probability you need a single object instead of many separate variables.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev the goal is to cut down the multiple lines of **before** and cut it down into an `.each()` function that will write it and I am unable to add `val` to the end of the `id` variable to declare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having each option as an individual variable, I would create an object to store all of your variable values.

```
var appOptions = { };

$(".settings select").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).prop('id');
  appOptions[id] = $(this).val();
});
```

This approach has the risk of becoming unpredictable if you forget to put an id on a select element in the selector, so you might want to add some validation:

```
if (!id) throw 'select without id';
```

As an aside: you got the id value from `attr()` in your code.  You're supposed to use `prop()`.
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: in my **before** example the id name has the letters 'val' after it. how can this be introduced?

Comment: appOptions[id + 'val']

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array` and `object`.

Try this:

```
var ary = [];
$(".settings select").each(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = $(this).attr('id');
    obj.val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    ary.push(obj);
});
console.log(ary);
```

`ary` will contain objects containing ids and values.

Comment: What's the point of the array? Why not just use the ids as object keys?

Comment: I think @beardy wants id and value of select box

Comment: Yes, and you can store the id in the keys just as well. If you have an array with separate objects it'll be a pain to find anything from there.